# How to Pair elements from a list without repeating the same combination?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools, shuffle

I have a list of elements, that I would like to group (of size 2,3,4 etc.) and find some unique combinations in each iteration.  I have the following snippet, that forms combinations of size *group_size* of *members*.

1. I would like to know how can I avoid duplicate combinations in the new iterations.
2. For *group_size* > 2, I want to also avoid any two elements of *members* repeating.  Let's say: *group_size* = 3; then *['A', 'B', 'C']* is accepted, but any other combination of *['A', 'B',~]* or *['B', 'C',~]* or *['A', 'C',~]* is not accepted in the future iterations, where '~' represents any element other than *['A', 'B', 'C']*.

```
import random
from itertools import zip_longest
members = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
group_size = 2
for i in range(10):
    random.shuffle(members)
    pairs_loc = [iter(members)] * group_size
    pairs = zip_longest(*pairs_loc)
    print(*pairs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I'm not sure I understood correctly what you want to do, but let me try, maybe it is useful to you all the same.

For the first point Python already has what (I believe that) you're looking for: `itertools.combinations`.

For the second point we need some code. One note: I'm sure you realize that with this second requirement you will have some cases when not all members appear in at least one combination: e.g., with 12 members and a `groupsize > 6`.

The code:

```
def select_combos(members, groupsize):
    assert groupsize > 1
    shuffle(members)
    if groupsize == 2:
        return list(combinations(members, 2))
    finalcombos = []
    usedcombos = []
    for c in combinations(members, groupsize):
        tempcombos = list(combinations(c, 2))
        for c2 in tempcombos:
            if c2 in usedcombos:
                break
        else:
            usedcombos += tempcombos
            finalcombos.append(c)
    return finalcombos

m = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
select_combos(m, 2)
[('C', 'A'), ('C', 'Z'), ('C', 'Y'), ('C', 'E'), ('C', 'W'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'U'), ('C', 'X'), ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'V'), ('C', 'F'), ('A', 'Z'), ('A', 'Y'), ('A', 'E'), ('A', 'W'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'U'), ('A', 'X'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'V'), ('A', 'F'), ('Z', 'Y'), ('Z', 'E'), ('Z', 'W'), ('Z', 'B'), ('Z', 'U'), ('Z', 'X'), ('Z', 'D'), ('Z', 'V'), ('Z', 'F'), ('Y', 'E'), ('Y', 'W'), ('Y', 'B'), ('Y', 'U'), ('Y', 'X'), ('Y', 'D'), ('Y', 'V'), ('Y', 'F'), ('E', 'W'), ('E', 'B'), ('E', 'U'), ('E', 'X'), ('E', 'D'), ('E', 'V'), ('E', 'F'), ('W', 'B'), ('W', 'U'), ('W', 'X'), ('W', 'D'), ('W', 'V'), ('W', 'F'), ('B', 'U'), ('B', 'X'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'V'), ('B', 'F'), ('U', 'X'), ('U', 'D'), ('U', 'V'), ('U', 'F'), ('X', 'D'), ('X', 'V'), ('X', 'F'), ('D', 'V'), ('D', 'F'), ('V', 'F')]

select_combos(m, 5)
[('W', 'V', 'C', 'U', 'E'), ('W', 'A', 'X', 'B', 'F'), ('V', 'A', 'D', 'Y', 'Z')]
```

**EDIT**
Now that it's clearer, the request for group size 2 is equivalent to scheduling a round-robin tournament, so we can use the [standard circle method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) here.

One quick and dirty implementation of the rotation:

```
def rotate(roster):
    half = (len(roster)+1)//2
    t=roster[1]
    roster[1] = roster[half]
    for j in range(half, len(roster)-1):
        roster[j] = roster[j+1]
    roster[-1] = roster[half-1]
    for j in range(half-1, 1, -1):
        roster[j] = roster[j-1]
    roster[2] = t

    for i in range(half):
        print(f'{roster[i]}-{roster[i+half]}   ', end = '')
    print()

members = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
shuffle(members)
for r in range(len(members)):
    rotate(members)
```

At each iteration this will rotate the roster one step and print the pairings. Note that at the n-th iteration the roster, and hence the pairings, will be the same as at the start.

Comment: Thank you, for *groupsize = 2*, I am expecting it to pair all the elements in list *m*.  Then there will be 6 pairs in iteration 1.  In the second iteration, it shuffles and makes new 6 pairs, where the pairs made in iteration 1 should not repeat.  This is my expection, sorry that my question is not quite clear.

Comment: This works as expected.  Do you have a recommendation, if size_of(members) is odd?  Then in that case, a random element will be without a pair in each iteration.  And also when group_size is 3 or 4, is it possible to group 3 or 4 elements in every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary of sets to keep track of the pairings that have already been used in previous groups.  Then assemble a new group based on the eligible members that you constrain with each addition to the group.  Note that it is possible to hit a dead-end so your group forming logic needs to be able to reset itself and start over with different random members:

```
import random
members = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

remaining  = {M:set(members)-{M} for M in members} # unused pairs by member
group_size = 3
for _ in range(10):
    more  = set()  # set of members that can be added to group
    group = []     # current group
    while len(group)<group_size:
        if len(more)+len(group)<group_size: # group not feasible
           more  = {m for m,r in remaining.items() if r} # reset
           group = [] 
        m = random.sample(more,1)[0] # select eligible member
        group.append(m)              # add to group 
        more &= remaining[m]         # constrain next members
    print(group)
    for m in group:                  # track unused pairs
        remaining[m].difference_update(group)   
        
['B', 'Z', 'Y']
['X', 'U', 'W']
['Y', 'U', 'C']
['D', 'Y', 'W']
['B', 'X', 'A']
['X', 'E', 'D']
['B', 'V', 'F']
['D', 'V', 'Z']
['E', 'A', 'F']
['A', 'C', 'Z']
```

Comment: Thank you.  This outputs, for each iteration, a list of *group_size*. But I am expecting it to output the *members* into *length(members)/ group_size* small groups.  And no two *members* of this iteration should be in the same group in the next iteration.  For example: *group_size = 3*, it outputs *members* into 4 small groups.